# Query database products by category

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a 3 table structure for categories products and catogory to products. The category table is has 3 lvl's cat/subcat/subbcat.

```
tbl_catalog_categories              tbl_products_to_categories
`id_category` smallint(6)           `id_record`
`id_parent` smallint(6)             `id_category`
`name` varchar(128)                 `id_product` 

tbl_products
`id_product`
```

So let's say i have the following entries for the categories `tbl_catalog_categories` :

```
1 0 Books
2 1 Action
3 2 Cops
```

and the linking table `tbl_products_to_categories` is

```
1 3 24
1 3 25
```

What i want is when i select the main category Books to get all the products from the subcategories and subsubcategories. So the result should be product id 24 and 25 when i select books.

Here is what i tryed, it's work's for 2 lvl's but i need another join for the third one and i can't manage make it work

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("Select p.name
FROM tbl_products p
INNER JOIN tbl_products_to_categories ptoc on ptoc.id_product=p.id_product
INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c1 on ptoc.id_category=c1.id_category
INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c2 on c1.id_parent=c2.id_category 

WHERE c2.name=:id and p.active=1 and p.quantity=1");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` (you'll need it twice).

Answer (score -1):

just convert your linking table to a hierarchical representation
like this for example :

http://moinne.com/blog/ronald/mysql/manage-hierarchical-data-with-mysql-stored-procedures